# Making http request from PHP file with JSON response

Tags: php, json, http

I am in the process of trying to call a php script over http and receive a json object back from where I plan to process further.

Basically, the code is as follows:

```
<?php
    if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'GET') {
        $version=$_GET["v"];
        $product=$_GET["p"];
        $stream=$_GET["s"];
        $cmd=$_GET["c"];

        $string = file_get_contents("http://localhost:82/releasenote/src/getTSBDetails.php?p=$product&v=$version&s=$stream&c=$cmd");
        print_r($string);
        exit();
    } else {
        print("2");
        $string = file_get_contents('tsbDetails.json');
    }
```

When the get_file_contents http request is called directly in the browser, the output is a json, but when trying using the above there is no response.

Comment: Is your machine == localhost?

Comment: can you narrow it down more? which of the cases is not working? how do you "use" it (in an ajax call, directly in the browser)?

Comment: _"there is no response"_ - that's impossible. What do you mean by _"but when trying to use the above"_? If you POST it? It should then output a '2'. You don't `echo $string` in the else.

Answer (score 2):

[image]

```
<?php
        // JSon request format is :
        // {"userName":"654321@zzzz.com","password":"12345","emailProvider":"zzzz"}

        // read JSon input
        $data_back = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'));

        // set json string to php variables
        $userName = $data_back->{"userName"};
        $password = $data_back->{"password"};
        $emailProvider = $data_back->{"emailProvider"};

        // create json response
        $responses = array();
        for ($i = 0; $i < 10; $i++) {
            $responses[] = array("name" => $i, "email" => $userName . " " . $password . " " . $emailProvider);
        }

        // JSon response format is :
        // [{"name":"eeee","email":"eee@zzzzz.com"},
        // {"name":"aaaa","email":"aaaaa@zzzzz.com"},{"name":"cccc","email":"bbb@zzzzz.com"}]

        // set header as json![enter image description here][2]
        header("Content-type: application/json");

        // send response
        echo json_encode($responses);
        ?>


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/I7imt.jpg
  [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/XgvOT.jpg
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all you should make sure your variables can be used in the url:

```
    $version=urlencode($_GET["v"]);
    $product=urlencode($_GET["p"]);
    $stream=urlencode($_GET["s"]);
    $cmd=urlencode($_GET["c"]);
```

Then you should check if the value you read in `$string` is valid json. You can use [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2348181/42139) for that.

Then, if your string contains valid json, you should just `echo` it.

Finally, if you always expect json from your script, you should also json_encode your error handling:

```
} else {
    echo json_encode("2");
    // $string = file_get_contents('tsbDetails.json');  /* commented out as you don't seem to use it */
}
```