# json_decode returns JSON_ERROR_SYNTAX but online formatter says the JSON is OK

Tags: php, json

I got a very strange problem.

I have a JSON webservice.

When i check it with this website http://www.freeformatter.com/json-formatter.html#ad-output

Everything is OK.

But when i load my JSON with this code :

```
  $data = file_get_contents('http://www.mywebservice');

if(!empty($data))
{

    $obj = json_decode($data);

 switch (json_last_error()) {
    case JSON_ERROR_NONE:
        echo ' - JSON_ERROR_NONE';
    break;
    case JSON_ERROR_DEPTH:
        echo ' - JSON_ERROR_DEPTH';
    break;
    case JSON_ERROR_STATE_MISMATCH:
        echo ' - JSON_ERROR_STATE_MISMATCH';
    break;
    case JSON_ERROR_CTRL_CHAR:
        echo ' -  JSON_ERROR_CTRL_CHAR';
    break;
    case JSON_ERROR_SYNTAX:
        echo "\r\n\r\n - SYNTAX ERROR \r\n\r\n";
    break;
    case JSON_ERROR_UTF8:
        echo ' - JSON_ERROR_UTF8';
    break;
    default:
        echo ' - Unknown erro';
    break;
}
```

I got the error : SYNTAX ERROR

WHICH IS NOT HELP FULL AT ALL.

It is a nightmare.

I see that with PHP 5.5 i could use this function : http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-last-error-msg.php

(but i did not succeed to install PHP 5.5 yet, and i m not sure this function will give me more detail)

Comment: Please show the JSON.

Comment: JSON please. We need your JSON.

Comment: Maybe you should make your error messages more verbose?  For example, include the JSON with the error message?

Answer (score 94):

I faced the same issue, actually there are some hidden characters unseen and you need to remove it.
Here's a global code that works for many cases:

```
<?php
$checkLogin = file_get_contents("http://yourwebsite.com/JsonData");

// This will remove unwanted characters.
// Check http://www.php.net/chr for details
for ($i = 0; $i <= 31; ++$i) { 
    $checkLogin = str_replace(chr($i), "", $checkLogin); 
}
$checkLogin = str_replace(chr(127), "", $checkLogin);

// This is the most common part
// Some file begins with 'efbbbf' to mark the beginning of the file. (binary level)
// here we detect it and we remove it, basically it's the first 3 characters 
if (0 === strpos(bin2hex($checkLogin), 'efbbbf')) {
   $checkLogin = substr($checkLogin, 3);
}

$checkLogin = json_decode( $checkLogin );
print_r($checkLogin);
?>
```

Comment: Dear sir, you have no idea how much this helped me. I looked everywhere for the solution and i almost gave up. Sir you are a godsend.

Comment: Still wondering why this is not part of core PHP at version 7.0.x. (face palm)

Comment: +1 for BOM, didn't come to mind. @GeorgeOnofrei, single responsibility principle would dictate that it's not the purpose of this function to perform sanitization if the string contains invalid chars, or a BOM which is technically not part of the JSON document itself!

Comment: This helped in my case...
`for ($i = 0; $i <= 31; ++$i) { 
    $checkLogin = str_replace(chr($i), "", $checkLogin); 
}`
But why??

Comment: I was getting this error from a payment gateway API response. This was the fix for the syntax error. Specifically filtering out the 'efbbbf'.

Comment: anyway I can view this hidden char ?

Answer (score 65):

Removing the `BOM` (Byte Order Mark) is often-times the solution you need:

```
function removeBOM($data) {
    if (0 === strpos(bin2hex($data), 'efbbbf')) {
       return substr($data, 3);
    }
    return $data;
}
```

You shouldn't have a BOM, but if it's there, it is invisible so you won't see it!!

see [W3C on BOM's in HTML](http://www.w3.org/International/questions/qa-byte-order-mark.en.php)

use [BOM Cleaner](https://github.com/emrahgunduz/BomCleaner/blob/master/bom.php) if you have lot's of files to fix.

Comment: I have changed encoding from `UTF-8` TO `UTF-8 without BOM` by `Notepad++` from `top menu of Notepad++>Format>UTF-8 without BOM`

Comment: Lost almost 1 hour trying a million things before finding this answer... thanks heaps!

Answer (score 34):

I solved this issue adding **stripslashes** to the string, before json_decode.

```
$data = stripslashes($data); 
$obj = json_decode($data);
```

Comment: This doesn't work for me like [the `removeBOM()` answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31594983/3416774)

Answer (score 7):

To put all things together here and there, I've prepared JSON wrapper with decoding auto corrective actions. Most recent version can be found in my [GitHub Gist](https://gist.github.com/KrzysztofPrzygoda/2eecd1e6a477a9707f3876ca2693fdb8).

```
abstract class Json
{
    public static function getLastError($asString = FALSE)
    {
        $lastError = \json_last_error();

        if (!$asString) return $lastError;

        // Define the errors.
        $constants = \get_defined_constants(TRUE);
        $errorStrings = array();

        foreach ($constants["json"] as $name => $value)
            if (!strncmp($name, "JSON_ERROR_", 11))
                $errorStrings[$value] = $name;

        return isset($errorStrings[$lastError]) ? $errorStrings[$lastError] : FALSE;
    }

    public static function getLastErrorMessage()
    {
        return \json_last_error_msg();
    }

    public static function clean($jsonString)
    {
        if (!is_string($jsonString) || !$jsonString) return '';

        // Remove unsupported characters
        // Check http://www.php.net/chr for details
        for ($i = 0; $i <= 31; ++$i)
            $jsonString = str_replace(chr($i), "", $jsonString);

        $jsonString = str_replace(chr(127), "", $jsonString);

        // Remove the BOM (Byte Order Mark)
        // It's the most common that some file begins with 'efbbbf' to mark the beginning of the file. (binary level)
        // Here we detect it and we remove it, basically it's the first 3 characters.
        if (0 === strpos(bin2hex($jsonString), 'efbbbf')) $jsonString = substr($jsonString, 3);

        return $jsonString;
    }

    public static function encode($value, $options = 0, $depth = 512)
    {
        return \json_encode($value, $options, $depth);
    }

    public static function decode($jsonString, $asArray = TRUE, $depth = 512, $options = JSON_BIGINT_AS_STRING)
    {
        if (!is_string($jsonString) || !$jsonString) return NULL;

        $result = \json_decode($jsonString, $asArray, $depth, $options);

        if ($result === NULL)
            switch (self::getLastError())
            {
                case JSON_ERROR_SYNTAX :
                    // Try to clean json string if syntax error occured
                    $jsonString = self::clean($jsonString);
                    $result = \json_decode($jsonString, $asArray, $depth, $options);
                    break;

                default:
                    // Unsupported error
            }

        return $result;
    }
}
```

Example usage:

```
$json_data = file_get_contents("test.json");
$array = Json::decode($json_data, TRUE);
var_dump($array);
echo "Last error (" , Json::getLastError() , "): ", Json::getLastError(TRUE), PHP_EOL;
```

Comment: I've been fighting with a weirdly encoded file containing JSON all day and this class finally got me a usable PHP array - thank you!

Comment: Worked for me like a charm! Thank you so much!!

Answer (score 7):

in my case:

**json_decode(html_entity_decode($json_string));**

Answer (score 4):

I have the same problem, receiving **JSON_ERROR_CTRL_CHAR** and **JSON_ERROR_SYNTAX**.
This is my fix.

```
$content = json_decode(json_encode($content), true);
```

Answer (score 3):

After trying all the solution without the result this is the one worked for me.

Hope it will help someone

```
$data = str_replace('&quot;', '"', $data);
```

Answer (score 1):

You haven't show your JSON  but this sound like it could be an Invalid UTF-8 sequence in argument, most online validator wont catch it.
make sure your data is UTF-8 and also check if you have foreign characters.
You don't need PHP5 to see your error, use [error_log()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-log.php) to log the problems.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issues. I took the following steps:

1. changed the JSON text encoding

   ```
   $json = utf8_encode($json);
   ```
2. I then viewed the plain text before decoding. I found crazy symbols like

   `ï`
3. then I just stripped it off

   ```
   $json = str_replace(array('ï',''), '',$json);
   ```

   and I successfully decoded my JSON

Answer (score 1):

please first clean json data and then load.

Answer (score 1):

A JSON string must be double-quoted, the JSON isn't valid because you don't need to escape `'` character.

```
char = unescaped /
  escape (
      %x22 /          ; "    quotation mark  U+0022
      %x5C /          ; \    reverse solidus U+005C
      %x2F /          ; /    solidus         U+002F
      %x62 /          ; b    backspace       U+0008
      %x66 /          ; f    form feed       U+000C
      %x6E /          ; n    line feed       U+000A
      %x72 /          ; r    carriage return U+000D
      %x74 /          ; t    tab             U+0009
      %x75 4HEXDIG )  ; uXXXX                U+XXXX
```

The `'` is not in the list.

See this list of special character used in JSON:

```
\b  Backspace (ascii code 08)
\f  Form feed (ascii code 0C)
\n  New line
\r  Carriage return
\t  Tab
\"  Double quote
\\  Backslash character
```

Check out [this](http://json.org/) site for more documentation.

Answer (score 1):

I faced this issue as well and it was so frustrating for me. after hours of trying different solutions on the internet. I noticed that the encoding of the file is in **UTF-8 with BOM** as var_dump() was echoing a weird character **&#65279;** before the JSON.

I converted the sample.json file I was working with from **UTF-8 with BOM** to **UTF-8** ... In VS CODE add the below to your settings.json or make sure the below settings code is as seen below (so that any file you create will be encoded in UTF-8 by default;

```
"files.encoding": "utf8",
```

Then you'll see something like the below screenshot on your VSCode toolbar. (For `json_decode()` to work, the file has to be encoded in UTF-8)

[image]

But in my case, the JSON file I created was having a **UTF-8 with BOM** encoding which is why when I was doing `json_decode($json, true)` it was returning null (Syntax Error when I `var_dump(json_last_error_msg())` )

[image]

1. Click on the **UTF-8 with BOM**, then you will get the dropdown,
2. Click **Save with Encoding**,
3. You should get the below screenshot, then you click on **UTF-8**.

[image]

That will resave your file with UTF-8 encoding and you can go ahead and check your code. `json_decode()` will work fine. Can't believe I spent hours trying to figure out what could be wrong.

Happy Coding!

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue, The reason is the responsed texts look like a json, but it is actually a text in HTML format. You can echo your text (json look-alike) in JSON format, to see what is actual inside:

```
$response = file_get_contents('http://www.mywebservice');
header('Content-Type: application/json');
echo $response;
```

This function **file_get_contents** will return some extra HTML codes.
In my case, I remove those unwanted characters :

```
$response = str_replace('<head></head><body><pre style="word-wrap: break-word; white-space: pre-wrap;">', '',$response );
$response = str_replace('</pre></body>', '',$response );
```

Here is the complete code:

```
$response = file_get_contents('http://www.mywebservice');
$response = str_replace('<head></head><body><pre style="word-wrap: break-word; white-space: pre-wrap;">', '',$response );
$response = str_replace('</pre></body>', '',$response );
$response = json_decode($response);
header('Content-Type: application/json');            
$error = json_last_error_msg() ;
echo $error;

if ($error == null){echo "This is truly a JSON : <br>"}
echo $response;
```

Answer (score -1):

One problem from my side, is that there were some invalid numbers starting with 0, Ex: "001", "002", "003".

```
     "expectedToBeReturned":1,
     "inventoryNumber":001,
     "remindNote":"",
```

Replace 001 with 1 and it works.

Answer (score -2):

I had same issue. For me it was causing by `echo "<br/><pre>"`. I was trying to pass json string to another php file using `exit(json_encode(utf8ize($resp_array)));` At the beginning of file i had decleared *break line* tag... So this was error for me. Removing this *break line tag* , i was able to decoding my json string an other php file..

Answer (score -2):

I had same issue. For me it was causing by `echo "<br/><pre>"`.

I was trying to pass json string to another php file using :

```
exit(json_encode(utf8ize($resp_array)));
```

At the beginning of file I had decleared break line tag... So this was error for me. Removing this break line tag , I was able to [...]

Comment: this isn't the same issue as described in the question, but it is a very common type of problem and can be hard to spot so it is good to have it mentioned.

Answer (score -2):

This code worked for me.
Basically it removes hidden characters.

```
    function cleanString($val)
    {
        $non_displayables = array(
        '/%0[0-8bcef]/',            # url encoded 00-08, 11, 12, 14, 15
        '/%1[0-9a-f]/',             # url encoded 16-31
        '/[\x00-\x08]/',            # 00-08
        '/\x0b/',                   # 11
        '/\x0c/',                   # 12
        '/[\x0e-\x1f]/',            # 14-31
        '/x7F/'                     # 127
        );
        foreach ($non_displayables as $regex)
        {
            $val = preg_replace($regex,'',$val);
        }
        $search  = array("\0","\r","\x1a","\t");
        return trim(str_replace($search,'',$val));
    }
```