# Unordered list, load <li> dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, json

I am creating a jquery slider using flickerplate.
This is the code when i hardcode the values and it works.

```
<div class="flicker-example">

    <ul>
            <li data-background="lib/flicker-1.jpg">
            <div class="flick-title">Promo 1</div>
            <div class="flick-sub-text">25$ OFF FLAT !! Limited Offer!</div>
        </li>

        <li data-background="lib/flicker-2.jpg">
            <div class="flick-title">Promo 2</div>
            <div class="flick-sub-text">Bumper Sale !! Buy 1 Get 1 Free !!</div>
        </li>           
    </ul>
</div>
```

My requirement is to load the content in it using my JSON array.

```
<div class="flicker-example">
    <ul>
       <script type='text/javascript'>
        $(document).ready(function(){
                    /* call the php that has the php array which is json_encoded */
                $.getJSON('http://testdb2.weby.biz/deallist.php', function(data) {
                        /* data will hold the php array as a javascript object */
                        $.each(data, function(key, val) {
                            $(".flicker-example ul").append('<li data-background="'+ val.Product_Variant_Image + '"><div class="flick-title">' + val.Product_Brand_Name + '</div><div class="flick-sub-text">' + val.Product_Variant_Name + '</div></li>');
                        });
                });

        });
        </script>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Above is my code, I can't figure out why is it not working like the hard coded one.
Could really use some help, thanks a lot

Comment: Can you show me the error, if any, in console window of browser?

Comment: @VipulHadiya This is how the hardcoded slider looks like http://imgur.com/AXUFNLx and this is the dyanamic one http://imgur.com/Wxlaeqb

Comment: I was asking to show error in console window. Right press F12 in chrome browser and show if there is any error or not. Or right click and select Inspect Element and from developers tool choose Console tab.

Comment: @VipulHadiya actually i'm developing this phonegap application so it doesn't run on browsers and i don't get any error in the emulator.

Comment: try alert(JSON.stringify(data)); to peek the data result inside the function

Comment: @bondythegreat the data is being retrieved, the problem is with the orientation. the data-background attribute in li is not working and the orientation of the other two div's is not as it should be..
hardcoded= imgur.com/AXUFNLx JSON= imgur.com/Wxlaeqb

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like the initialisation of the plugin happens on DOM load. Perhaps you have some code that looks like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.flicker-example').flickerplate();
});
```

That works fine when the content is hard-coded HTML, because it exists when that code executes. However, you're using an asynchronous request to load JSON data, so the order of execution looks something like this:

1. DOM ready
2. Flickerplate initialised
3. JSON AJAX request sent
4. JSON response returned
5. HTML created

You need 2 to actually happen last, as step 5, so change the callback function for your `$.getJSON` call:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    /* call the php that has the php array which is json_encoded */
    $.getJSON('http://testdb2.weby.biz/deallist.php', function(data) {
        /* data will hold the php array as a javascript object */
        $.each(data, function(key, val) {
            $(".flicker-example ul").append('<li data-background="'+ val.Product_Variant_Image + '"><div class="flick-title">' + val.Product_Brand_Name + '</div><div class="flick-sub-text">' + val.Product_Variant_Name + '</div></li>');
        });
        $('.flicker-example').flickerplate(); // initialise the plugin now that the HTML elements exist
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Test this :
Activate CORS (Cross-Origin Request) on your server.
Apache example : in your .htaccess file

```
Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
```

Or in code PHP

```
 header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

$checkLogin = file_get_contents("http://testdb2.weby.biz/deallist.php");

// This will remove unwanted characters.
// Check http://www.php.net/chr for details
for ($i = 0; $i <= 31; ++$i) { 
    $checkLogin = str_replace(chr($i), "", $checkLogin); 
}
$checkLogin = str_replace(chr(127), "", $checkLogin);

// This is the most common part
// Some file begins with 'efbbbf' to mark the beginning of the file. (binary level)
// here we detect it and we remove it, basically it's the first 3 characters 
if (0 === strpos(bin2hex($checkLogin), 'efbbbf')) {
   $checkLogin = substr($checkLogin, 3);
}

//$checkLogin = json_decode( $checkLogin );
//print_r($checkLogin);

?>




<div class="flicker-example">
    <ul>
       <script type='text/javascript'>
        $(document).ready(function(){
                    /* call the php that has the php array which is json_encoded */
                //$.getJSON('http://testdb2.weby.biz/deallist.php', function(data) {
            //alert(JSON.stringify(data));
                        /* data will hold the php array as a javascript object */
        $.each(<?php echo $checkLogin; ?>, function(key, val) {
                            $(".flicker-example ul").append('<li data-background="'+ val.Product_Variant_Image + '"><div class="flick-title">' + val.Product_Brand_Name + '</div><div class="flick-sub-text">' + val.Product_Variant_Name + '</div></li>');
                        });
                //});

        });
        </script>
    </ul>
</div>
```

For more details : [json_decode returns JSON_ERROR_SYNTAX but online formatter says the JSON is OK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17219916/json-decode-returns-json-error-syntax-but-online-formatter-says-the-json-is-ok)

Answer (score 0):

If your array(data) is in proper format as shown below:

```
arr[0]
Object {title: "Promo 1", text: "25$ OFF FLAT !! Limited Offer!"}
arr[1]
Object {title: "Promo 2", text: "Bumper Sale !! Buy 1 Get 1 Free !!"}
```

Then Check out this fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/n1su1q0h/1/