# empty response php sql json

Tags: php, json, mysqli

i am developing a php server sending arrays response to Android client using JSON. Now i simply testing the php code but the result is empty. Please help!!

```
<?php 
            #Connect to Database 
            $con = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","", "leoonline"); 

            #Check connection 
            if (mysqli_connect_errno()) { 
                echo 'Database connection error: ' . mysqli_connect_error(); 
                exit(); 
            } 

            //Check already exist account
            $allaccount = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM usersacc");
            $results = array();
            while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($allaccount))
            {
               $results[] = array(
                  'id' => base64_decode($row['id']),
                  'phone' => $row['phone'],
                  'password'> $row['password']
               );
            }
            $json = json_encode($results);

    ?>
```

Comment: What happens when you put loop inside if ($allaccount){while(){...} var_dump($json);}

Comment: does your table usersacc contains necessary data?

Comment: Read this answer : 

[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17219916/json-decode-returns-json-error-syntax-but-online-formatter-says-the-json-is-ok][1]


  [1]: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17219916/json-decode-returns-json-error-syntax-but-online-formatter-says-the-json-is-ok

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this your final code? You are not outputting anything apart from the connection error message if it happens.

Change

```
 $json = json_encode($results);
```

to

```
 echo json_encode($results);
```

If its still blank, then it could be a db data problem.