# PHP json_decode return error code 4

Tags: php, json, string, character-encoding, json-deserialization

I had previously asked the same question. I would like to decode the json from: http://pad.skyozora.com/data/pets.json. Below is the code I used previously:

```
<?php
$html=file_get_contents("http://pad.skyozora.com/data/pets.json");
var_dump(json_decode($html,true)); //return null
var_dump(json_last_error()); // return 4
?>
```

From the last answer I know there is UTF8 DOM in the json return. I tried the answer from a similar question: [json_decode returns NULL after webservice call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/689185/json-decode-returns-null-after-webservice-call), but all of the answers not work for me.

And after do more research I found a way that works:

```
<?php
$html=file_get_contents("http://pad.skyozora.com/data/pets.json");
$html=preg_replace('/[\x00-\x1F\x80-\xFF]/', '', $html);
var_dump(json_decode($html, true));
var_dump(json_last_error());
?>
```

This successfully decode the json into array. However all Chinese and Japanese character string were removed too. Any ideas?

**Edited:**

I used http://jsonlint.com/ to decode the json from http://pad.skyozora.com/data/pets.json. It stops at here:

```
[
            161,
            "進化的紅面具",
            0,
            -1,
            0,
        -1,
        1,
        1,
        10,
        50,
        1,
        0,
        0,
        0,
        0,
        [

        ],
        [
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0
        ],
        "http:\/\/i.imgur.com\/Y1jZlGW.png",
        [
            "ウルカヌ火山",
            "メジェド
```

and give me the error:

```
Parse error on line 5001:
...山",                "メジェド
----------------------^
Expecting 'STRING', 'NUMBER', 'NULL', 'TRUE', 'FALSE', '{', '['
```

But I couldn't see any problem with this part of json.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [json\_decode returns JSON\_ERROR\_SYNTAX but online formatter says the JSON is OK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17219916/json-decode-returns-json-error-syntax-but-online-formatter-says-the-json-is-ok)

Comment: For me NaN was the problem, using df.fillna('', inplace=True) fix the problem in case if you used pandas

Answer (score 10):

The return error code 4 is due to a `JSON_ERROR_SYNTAX` you must try to fix your json.

If you go to the url in a browser you can see this message:

```
bad character in string literal at line 1 column 294388
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, how to resolve the syntax error?

Comment: @NgYatPing Well this is a hard road, first search where it fail and post the code.

Comment: I have edited the question with validator result from http://jsonlint.com/ . But I don't see any problem with it....

Comment: @NgYatPing Change the value where the validator stop and see waht happens

Comment: @NgYatPing you got some advance?

Comment: Hi Adrian, finally I still cannot get to decode the json through json_decode(). I used http://jsonformat.com/#jsondataurllabel to help me decode instead... And I still don't know the reason...