# Accessing a JSON value with a php $Key value

Tags: php, json

While answering [Get JSON object from URL Difficulties](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32845286/get-json-object-from-url-difficulties/32846688#32846688), I noticed one of the JSON names was `"$id"`:

```
{ "data" : [
    {
        "$id": "1",
        "SearchKey": "Alnwick |Alnwick",
        ...
```

This caused the following php code to throw different errors:

```php
$json = ... //json above
$obj = json_decode($json);
echo property_exists($obj->data[0], '$id'); // prints true
echo $obj->data[0]->$id; // PHP Fatal Error: Cannot access empty property ...
echo $obj->data[0]->id; // PHP Notice: Undefined property stdClass::$id ...
echo $obj->data[0]->'$id'; // PHP Parse Error: syntax error, unexpected ''$id'' (T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING) ...
```

Assuming the json is decoded as objects not arrays, how can I access the `"$id"` field?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Accessing the variable via `{'invalid-parameter-name'}` works:

```
 echo $obj->data[0]->{'$id'}; // 1
```