# How to convert string response into JSON object?

Tags: php, json, curl

I'm calling a third party api using `curl` from a php function. I'm getting a response in JSON format (datatype is string). I want convert that response to an object or array. I have tried `json_decode()`, but I'm getting `null`. If I display response in browser and copy paste that string response in PHP variable, I get the value. So I can't figure out what the problem is.

Here is my code:

```
$fullUrl = 'http://example.com/api/assignment/1';
$data = AesCtr::encrypt($data, 'My Key', 256);
$curl = curl_init($fullUrl);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'POST');
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, ['data' => $data]);
$curl_response = curl_exec($curl);
$curl_response = json_decode($curl_response);
echo '<pre>';
print_r($curl_response);
```

Here is response:

```
{"identifier":"id", "items":[{"apiResult":"INVALID", "apiResultMessage":"Invalid controls. the field 'resource' is mandatory the field 'type of item' is mandatory the field 'element id' is mandatory the field 'resource' is mandatory", "id":"", "idProject":"", "nameProject":"", "refType":"", "refId":"", "idResource":"", "nameResource":"", "idRole":"", "nameRole":"", "comment":"", "assignedWork":"", "realWork":"", "leftWork":"", "plannedWork":"", "rate":"", "realStartDate":"", "realEndDate":"", "plannedStartDate":"", "plannedEndDate":"", "dailyCost":"", "newDailyCost":"", "assignedCost":"", "realCost":"", "leftCost":"", "plannedCost":"", "idle":"", "billedWork":""}] }
```

**I also have tried this**

```
$curl_response = str_replace("'", "\'", $curl_response);
$curl_response = json_decode($curl_response);
```

Comment: JSON string seems valid, http://json-parser.com/a7826645 try to check the  JSON decoding error message using `json_last_error_msg()`

Comment: Please don't randomly boldface parts of your question, it makes it much harder to read.

Comment: @Anant, I have showed response in question.

Comment: @AlokPatel, I know that the JSON is valid. But my question is that then why I can't decode it?

Comment: @Anant, Yes, that is the response. But remember that it is in string datatype. Here it looks like object because I have copy/paste from browser.

Comment: @AkshayVaghasiya Check error message using json_last_error_msg()

Comment: @AlokPatel, I'm getting `unexpected character`.

Comment: @AlokPatel, See updated question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:-

```
$curl_response = curl_exec($curl);

function escapeJsonString($value) { 
    $escapers = array("\'");
    $replacements = array("\\/");
    $result = str_replace($escapers, $replacements, $value);
    return $result;
}



$curl_response = escapeJsonString($curl_response);

$curl_response = json_decode($curl_response,true);

echo '<pre>';print_r($curl_response);

echo $error = json_last_error();
```

Reference taken:- http://www.pontikis.net/tip/?id=5

The link you found useful is:- https://stackoverflow.com/a/20845642/4248328

Comment: problem solved. I got solution from [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17219916/json-decode-returns-json-error-syntax-but-online-formatter-says-the-json-is-ok). See comment `the most common part`.

Answer (score 1):

Try add second param "assoc" for getting array to json_decode function:

`$curl_response = json_decode($curl_response, true);`

Hope it'll help.