# PHP json_decode returns null value because of syntax error

Tags: php, json

```
$foo_json = '{"hoge":"ywwxEu|`tYdBeARGJ?nJ~BHHmDjX|PdEl@Rj@\\XVtKtK\\VbKnFrIbEzEbBnEbBfDfAxBz@LJjBl@jEzAfZzKDPY|DUdCGbAFL?|AD~AJ\\LNPJ~B|@p@Ll@FRDd@RvBnAfA`@dAl@^NhAVd@@p@?h@H`@Pv@l@TR^f@`Rd@xAFdEVnCLjJn@Cn@FlRDh@HRHHjKpG\\\\jC`G|EvJ|BjGf@vAJh@nGpC`FrBbG`D~@XdBRnNtAnTdBf@Jn@Zf@h@pB`DrD|EZl@jBfEf@`Af@r@tCpChFrG~@zAx@dBdB~Cz@xA`AxA|@l@f@VdDrAnAl@jI~CpCv@|@f@~An@jIxD~CdAzAl@rCvAjI|CzJpClJbCvLdDbn@lH`d@pF~Df@dDn@hA`@hBfA~AbAzQpMvHhFhQ~L~G`FtBrArCnBbBnAjB`A`~@~^tBx@n@RfB\\b@Fh@B|BBpV{AfSgArJq@~@?dBF`Cd@nFjAhXdG~@VtMpEd[fKfL|DxWrI~Y`KvLtDp\\zK|DnAzBbAbA|@rAtApAfBhA`Cl@fBh@lBtEpQh@fBrAjFdDpLdArCj@fAd@x@`BvBlDnDrVxWjDzD`GlGhCvBvBvA|DjBlC|@hTvEfBNvABvISxUo@|JSlA@tBLt@LdAXv@ZnB~@~@t@xAnAf@f@xEdEzAbBzAnBlWp_@bAnBlBpE|@tChBdFhBjGzCnJrCdHp@jAxAxBlGvH~@|Ab@bAp@xBnCdMd@pBl@fBt@bB\\j@v@lAxUlUtCjCdBz@nJdIdJbIrH`H~F|EjDxCzAnBNb@HdAJ|Fb@jDTpHq@@"}';
$foo = json_decode($foo_json);
```

I wrote this code, but json_decode returns null, and json_last_error() returns "JSON_ERROR_SYNTAX".
So I know there are some syntax errors, but I tried the string at [JSONLint](https://jsonlint.com/), they say Valid JSON.

Probably the reason why because the string is complicated and includes symbols.
I do not understand what is wrong.

PHP5.6.33

CentOS release 6.6

The answer is here.
The problem was backslashes, and I do not like to remove it.
[json_decode returns JSON_ERROR_SYNTAX but online formatter says the JSON is OK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17219916/json-decode-returns-json-error-syntax-but-online-formatter-says-the-json-is-ok)
Above article says just remove it, in this case, I need to replace it.

```
$foo_json = str_replace('\\', '\\\\', $foo_json);
```

I added this code, then it works fine.

Comment: "So I know there are some syntax errors, but I tried the string at JSONLint, they say Valid JSON" — When I try it, it throws up errors.

Comment: @Quentin really? I got no errors

Comment: @IslamElshobokshy — Really. Make sure you try to validate your JSON and not the PHP source code for the string literal.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [json\_decode returns JSON\_ERROR\_SYNTAX but online formatter says the JSON is OK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17219916/json-decode-returns-json-error-syntax-but-online-formatter-says-the-json-is-ok)

Comment: @Quentin I did and I honestly got no errors using JsonLint

Answer (score 1):

Look at the rules for strings in [JSON](http://json.org/):

[image: JSON strings]

A `\` character has a very limited set of characters it can be followed with.

Your input violates this several times:

e.g. `\\X` and `\\V`

Remember that `\` is a special character in PHP string literals so if you want an escaped `\` in JSON, you need to:

1. Escape the `\` with another `\` for JSON
2. Escape **each** of them with another `\` for PHP

… giving you 4 `\` characters.

Comment: $foo_json = str_replace('\\', '\\\\', $foo_json); Add this code, then works fine! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Try this below code

```
$foo_json =preg_replace('/\\\\/', '', $foo_json);
$foo = json_decode($foo_json);
  print_r( $foo);exit;
```

It's working fine.

Comment: While this creates JSON that will parse, it discards data from it. The slashes need to be escaped not discarded.

Comment: The problem is backslashes, but I don't like to remove it because I need 
the backslash data.

Answer (score -2):

json_(de|en)code needs to have UTF8 data. Check your input if it is UTF8 and if NOT, convert your input to UTF-8 and then use json_(de|en)code to get it ;)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. This is UTF-8 file, and other json_decode methods succeed with other strings.

Answer (score -2):

This should result in a valid response. (Handles line breaks and special escapes)

```
$json = str_replace("\n","\\n",$foo_json );
$json = str_replace("\r","",$json);
$json = preg_replace('/([{,]+)(\s*)([^"]+?)\s*:/','$1"$3":',$json);
$json = preg_replace('/(,)\s*}$/','}',$json);
var_dump($json);
```

Comment: Why the downvote? No need for UTF8 encoding or anything.. It's just becase of the escaped values that you need to correctly escape for PHP. The above code parsed your json string correctly..

Comment: I tested it with the code from the question. The output is still invalid JSON and does not parse.