# json_decode giving null on a valid json

Tags: php, json, curl

I have this text in my $result

> {"meta":{"code":400,"message":"Bad Request"},"error":"userId is required.","extras":null}

But when I do

```
$json_result = json_decode($result, true);
print_r($json_result);
```

It gives me **null**. I have validated this text everywhere and it says that it is a valid json.

**EDIT**

This is my code

```
<?php

$data = "&userId=";
$data_string = $data;
$url = 'http://apptellect.cloudapp.net/binance/api/v1/get_user_assets/';
$ch = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data_string);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
echo $result = curl_exec($ch);
echo '<hr>';
curl_close($ch);
$json_result = json_decode($result, true);
echo json_last_error_msg();
echo '<hr>';
//$json_result = json_decode( preg_replace('/[\x00-\x1F\x80-\xFF]/', '', $result), true );
print_r($json_result);
?>
```

Comment: It says 4 but I don't understand why does it say 4

Comment: Works for me on pretty much all PHP versions: https://3v4l.org/KNUdP perhaps you have some non-printing characters in there?

Comment: No just this text

Comment: 4 = "JSON_ERROR_SYNTAX" - http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-last-error.php. Show us how you're setting `$result`.

Comment: @Ali : It's works perfectly  please check output here   https://paiza.io/projects/E1XhDKs3CUEY7ab1L4O_8Q#&togetherjs=8Agn9OEgzN

Comment: Please check my actual code now @Abhijit

Comment: @AlivetoDie Please check the code that I did

Comment: @Utkanos Please check my code

Comment: @Nick Please verify my code.

Comment: Possible duplicates of:- [json_decode returns JSON_ERROR_SYNTAX but online formatter says the JSON is OK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17219916/json-decode-returns-json-error-syntax-but-online-formatter-says-the-json-is-ok)

Answer (score 2):

I have solved this issue please check this below code

```
<?php
// Your code here!
$data = "&userId=";
$data_string = $data;
$url = 'http://apptellect.cloudapp.net/binance/api/v1/get_user_assets/';
$ch = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data_string);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
echo $result = curl_exec($ch);
echo '<hr>';
curl_close($ch);

// This will remove unwanted characters.
// Check http://www.php.net/chr for details
for ($i = 0; $i <= 31; ++$i) { 
    $result = str_replace(chr($i), "", $result); 
}
$result = str_replace(chr(127), "", $result);

// This is the most common part
// Some file begins with 'efbbbf' to mark the beginning of the file. (binary level)
// here we detect it and we remove it, basically it's the first 3 characters 
if (0 === strpos(bin2hex($result), 'efbbbf')) {
   $result = substr($result, 3);
}

$json_result =    json_decode($result, true);

echo json_last_error_msg();
echo '<hr>';
print_r($json_result);

?>
```

I am sure it's work properly please check

Curl sent json response .it's display proper json but it's have unwanted characters. we have remove unwanted characters binary level.Then pass to json_decode function

**Happy Programming**

Thanks,
AS

Comment: @Ali Zia : Have you checked my answer ?

Comment: would you like to explain to us exactly what you've done in the code to solve it, in case it's not obvious what you have changed, and more importantly _why_ you changed it.

Comment: @ADyson : Curl sent json response .it's display proper json but it's have unwanted characters.  we have remove unwanted characters binary level.Then pass to json_decode function

Comment: please add the explanation to the answer itself - thanks.

Answer (score -1):

Hi I found that on stackoverflow: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17219916/json-decode-returns-json-error-syntax-but-online-formatter-says-the-json-is-ok)

```
<?php

function removeBOM($data) {
    if (0 === strpos(bin2hex($data), 'efbbbf')) {
       return substr($data, 3);
    }
    return $data;
}

$data = "&userId=";
$data_string = $data;
$url = 'http://apptellect.cloudapp.net/binance/api/v1/get_user_assets/';
$ch = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data_string);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

$result = curl_exec($ch);
$result = removeBOM($result);
echo $result;

curl_close($ch);
$json_result = json_decode(trim($result), false);
echo json_last_error_msg();
//$json_result = json_decode( preg_replace('/[\x00-\x1F\x80-\xFF]/', '', $result), true );
print_r($json_result);
?>
```

Comment: found what exactly? Can you explain your code please and how it solves the problem.

Comment: Please also explain the code so that I can understand what removeBOM is doing

Comment: jawbonewalk when you found a duplicate link then try to close the question with that link instead of re-answering the question with same code.

Answer (score -1):

just you need to add the trim before decoding your code.You will get the result as it is getting some extra data