# Find line with error in php json_decode

Tags: php, json

I have a large JSON file returned from a web service.  I am using json_last_error() to get the error code, but would like to know which string is giving the error so that I can design a regex for it.  How would I return the string giving the error?

Comment: use this http://jsonlint.com/

Comment: Check this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2348152/detect-bad-json-data-in-php-json-decode

Answer (score 0):

I know I'm late, but I was researching about this and my solution was this library:
https://github.com/Seldaek/jsonlint

With this library you can check the syntax of a JSON string and it gives you more detail than `json_last_error()` method do.