# "Trying to get property of non-object" error when running a Codeception test

Tags: php, phpunit, codeception

I have a Cest with a _before() that has the following code in it to authenticate (API testing):

```
// Log a user in
$I->haveHttpHeader('Accept', 'application/json');
$I->sendPOST('/authentication/login', ['username' => $this->username, 'password' => $this->password]);

$this->api_token = json_decode($I->grabResponse())->token;
```

When I run the test I get the following error:

```
[PHPUnit_Framework_Exception] Trying to get property of non-object  


Scenario Steps:

 3. $I->grabResponse() at tests/api/ApiBase.php:19
 2. $I->sendPOST("/authentication/login",{"username":"user@examplecom","password":"abc123"}) at tests/api/ApiBase.php:17
 1. $I->haveHttpHeader("Accept","application/json") at tests/api/ApiBase.php:16
```

`tests/api/ApiBase.php:19` is `$this->api_token = json_decode($I->grabResponse())->token;`

It appears as if `$I` is no longer an object, but I have confirmed that it is still an instance of `ApiTester`.  So the only thing I can think of is the call to the property of a non-object is somewhere deeper down.

How can I tell where?  I'm running this with the `--debug` switch enabled.

**[EDIT]** This isn't a problem with the `json_decode`.  If I move `$I->grabResponse()` up then the error will be on that line.

Comment: Probably return value of json_decode is not an object, so it doesn't have "token" property. You should add json_decode error handling (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2348152/detect-bad-json-data-in-php-json-decode)

Answer (score 2):

Validate response before using it.
[seeResponseJsonMatchesJsonPath](http://codeception.com/docs/modules/REST#seeResponseJsonMatchesJsonPath) checks if the element is present in json response.

```
$I->seeResponseJsonMatchesJsonPath('$.token');
```

Also it could be useful to use [grabDataFromResponseByJsonPath](http://codeception.com/docs/modules/REST#grabDataFromResponseByJsonPath) method instead of parsing it yourself.

```
$this->api_token = $I->grabDataFromResponseByJsonPath('$.token')[0];
```

`[0]` is necessary because grabDataFromResponseByJsonPath returns a list of matching items.

You may need to install `flow/jsonpath` library to get JsonPath methods working if it isn't installed yet.