# Getting data from a cookie

Tags: php, json, string, cookies, encode

I am outputting to my error log with this code:

```
ob_start();
var_dump($_COOKIE['agl-values']);
error_log(ob_get_clean());
```

The output is:

> [02-Apr-2018 16:12:58 UTC] string(321)
>   "{\"latitude\":\"42.2470259\",\"longitude\":\"-71.1755274\",\"altitude\":\"NaN\",\"accuracy\":\"29\",\"altitudeAccuracy\":\"NaN\",\"heading\":\"NaN\",\"speed\":\"NaN\",\"error_code\":\"\",\"error_message\":\"\",\"php_time\":1522684274,\"php_date\":\"2018-04-02
>   15:51:14\",\"php_date_format\":\"Y-m-d H:i:s\",\"user_id\":0}"
>
> [02-Apr-2018 16:12:58 UTC] string(321)
>   "{\"latitude\":\"42.2470259\",\"longitude\":\"-71.1755274\",\"altitude\":\"NaN\",\"accuracy\":\"29\",\"altitudeAccuracy\":\"NaN\",\"heading\":\"NaN\",\"speed\":\"NaN\",\"error_code\":\"\",\"error_message\":\"\",\"php_time\":1522684274,\"php_date\":\"2018-04-02
>   15:51:14\",\"php_date_format\":\"Y-m-d H:i:s\",\"user_id\":0}"
>
> [02-Apr-2018 16:12:58 UTC] string(321)
>   "{\"latitude\":\"42.2470259\",\"longitude\":\"-71.1755274\",\"altitude\":\"NaN\",\"accuracy\":\"29\",\"altitudeAccuracy\":\"NaN\",\"heading\":\"NaN\",\"speed\":\"NaN\",\"error_code\":\"\",\"error_message\":\"\",\"php_time\":1522684274,\"php_date\":\"2018-04-02
>   15:51:14\",\"php_date_format\":\"Y-m-d H:i:s\",\"user_id\":0}"
>
> [02-Apr-2018 16:12:58 UTC] string(321)
>   "{\"latitude\":\"42.2470259\",\"longitude\":\"-71.1755274\",\"altitude\":\"NaN\",\"accuracy\":\"29\",\"altitudeAccuracy\":\"NaN\",\"heading\":\"NaN\",\"speed\":\"NaN\",\"error_code\":\"\",\"error_message\":\"\",\"php_time\":1522684274,\"php_date\":\"2018-04-02
>   15:51:14\",\"php_date_format\":\"Y-m-d H:i:s\",\"user_id\":0}"

I just need to access the latitude and longitude variables. How do I isolate one of the cookies, and then how do I turn it into JSON?

**UPDATE**

I checked `json_last_error()` and it is telling me the string has a syntax error - could it be the escaped double quotes?

Comment: Try json decoding the string you get from `$_COOKIE['agl-values']` like so: `json_decode($_COOKIE['agl-values'])['latitude']`?

Comment: `var_dump(json_decode($_COOKIE['agl-values'])['latitude']);` returns `NULL`

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2348152/detect-bad-json-data-in-php-json-decode to check if the json is invalid. Use the `json_last_error()` function to find the specific error.

Comment: I figured out the `json_last_error()` and it says there is a syntax error

Comment: aren't there supposed to be single quotes in a json string?

Comment: I think it's because of the `\"`s. Try doing a `str_replace` to filter them out: `json_decode(str_replace('\"', '"', $_COOKIE['agl-values']))`

Comment: thanks @David that works - please provide an answer and i'll mark it correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like there's some escaped quotes in the json (`\"`) which means that the `json_decode` would fail with a syntax error. Try using `str_replace` to change them into regular quotes (`"`):

```
json_decode(str_replace('\"', '"', $_COOKIE['agl-values']))
```

Then, to get the latitude and longitude, do something like this:

```
$aglValues = json_decode(str_replace('\"', '"', $_COOKIE['agl-values']));

var_dump($aglValues->latitude);
var_dump($aglValues->longitude);
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like it’s stored as a string. Convert to a JSON object then reference:

```
$value = json_decode($_COOKIE['agl-values']);
echo $value->longitude . ' ' . $value->latitude;
```

**Update**

Here's a direct sample from your string:

```
php > $var = json_decode("{\"latitude\":\"42.2470259\",\"longitude\":\"-71.1755274\",\"altitude\":\"NaN\",\"accuracy\":\"29\",\"altitudeAccuracy\":\"NaN\",\"heading\":\"NaN\",\"speed\":\"NaN\",\"error_code\":\"\",\"error_message\":\"\",\"php_time\":1522684274,\"php_date\":\"2018-04-02 15:51:14\",\"php_date_format\":\"Y-m-d H:i:s\",\"user_id\":0}");
php > echo $var->longitude;
-71.1755274
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure this wont work...see updated question in a second

Comment: @ewizard yes. you probably copied/pasted bad quotes from SO

Comment: what should i do about it, i tried it exactly like in your update except using `$_COOKIE['agl-values']` instead of the string in string form and it still returns null

Comment: where are the bad quotes?

Comment: They were in my answer (I answered from my iPhone). What is the output of: json_decode($_COOKIE['agl-values']);?

Answer (score 0):

The cookie is already in JSON format, you need to decode it properly.

Use:

```
print_r(json_decode($_COOKIE['agl-values'], true));
```

Or for a single value:

```
echo json_decode($_COOKIE['agl-values'], true)['latitude'];
```

To use default json decode object:

```
echo json_decode($_COOKIE['agl-values'])->latitude;
```

Comment: the bottom two return null, i dont need to print

Comment: @ewizard Not according to https://3v4l.org/7Y75n , there was a issue with the the last line, but fixed in the update. I copyed the string directly from your error log.

Comment: yah....that appears to work...but when i use the cookie variable with the string in it...it doesn't

Comment: @ewizard Odd, what version of PHP are you running? According to the comments it is `\"` being someone escaped incorrectly. The suggested "fix" is to replace it with just `"`. However I would call that a patch as nothing is truely fixed and issues might arise in the future. What code causes the json generation in the first place?