# convert string received via file_get_contents to JSON object

Tags: php, json

I need to scrape JSON data.
Given link shows the scanned results in JSON format.

```
$json = file_get_contents('https://www.magereport.com/scan/result/?s=http://magento2-demo.nexcess.net/');
$obj = json_decode($json);
```

`$obj` is `NULL` always.
Is it possible this way?

[image: output of echo $json is in this pic.]

Comment: Its possible... if what you are getting is actually json. Show us an example of what comes from `echo $json;`?

Comment: That URL doesn't return JSON

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Detect bad json data in PHP json\_decode()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2348152/detect-bad-json-data-in-php-json-decode)

Comment: That output isn't one JSON string, it's many of them concatenated together, and there's no record separator. You'll have to split the string by balancing braces.

Comment: @iainn thank you. I didn't know it.

Comment: @MonkeyZeus No it isn't here we are talking about fetching string from URL.

Comment: @AlexHowansky okay thanks for the help. But can you please enlighten me, please.